# how to create keyof of multiType with string appender

Tags: typescript, keyof

I am having trouble with building `keyof` with mutitype

See below to know the issue

```js
export type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];

export type JoinNoneFunctionPropertyNames<T extends object, B extends object, D extends string> =  {
[Key in keyof (T & B) & ( string | number)]: (T & B)[Key] extends Function ? never : (T & B)[Key] extends object 
  ? `${D}.${Key}`
  : `${D}.${Key}`
  }[keyof (T & B) & (string | number)];
  

export interface IQuery<T extends object, D extends string, kType> {
Column: (columnName: kType) => IQuery<T, D, kType>;
InnerJoin: <B extends object>(tableName: D, columnNameA: kType | kType[], columnNameB: NonFunctionPropertyNames<B> | NonFunctionPropertyNames<B>[]) => IQuery<T & B, D, JoinNoneFunctionPropertyNames<T, B, D>>;
}

type TableNames = "TestA" | "TestB";

interface TestA {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    password: string;
    
}

interface TestB {
    fullName: string;
    id: number;
    alies: string;
    parentId: number;
}

const query = {} as IQuery<TestA, TableNames, NonFunctionPropertyNames<TestA>>


query.InnerJoin<TestB>("TestB", "id", "parentId").Column("")
```

Here is the issue with `JoinNoneFunctionPropertyNames`, in the above example `Column("")`
should present the following keys

```
TestA.name
TestA.id
TestA.password
TestB.id
TestB.alies
TestB.fullName
TestB.parentId
```

instead I am getting

```
TestA.name
TestA.id
TestA.password
TestA.alies
TestA.fullName
TestA.parentId
TestB.id
TestB.alies
TestB.fullName
TestB.parentId
TestB.name
TestB.password
```

how can I change `JoinNoneFunctionPropertyNames` so that I get the below values instead

```
TestA.name
TestA.id
TestA.password
TestB.id
TestB.alies
TestB.fullName
TestB.parentId
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-pxJjA6AV1cADepmhVdZqGJgDQBBI321A7Y0oITKKN62MGyrqWK3RLJahpRgsL3cHYF-AJciUEu0MtsSqcDOm818gVCwm2uDuuNYYCFuspGgGzIVSoSziOgIuen+JAoJTB0Pj3hwABE7BYMHjm-J293lU3NICLIc7M5Sl38cGtKB1jL6hlPRpj-E+nUmD2Byg78fMA6GYZgAHdoC-VYul6AC6X8edAn8C82Q5VAd06aplQfIF5FwdV1XDKD1jfZEgWISCf0pf9SLgOh1WIFgX2gjZYLgICoD0GAuQo38HBpBCAl1TBOjgABHS1EA3fgXFoowLS7dC9wqdhVzDJsKmrUwi3rVJGwyDhbxnBcAnEgVoWdV1+wMjCAyPDDNwqTdyIcrd2M47jN3maE1RjTBJjsvdoVw-CDU8gIgA)

Comment: I'm confused by what you're doing. There seems to be multiple issues with your code and the approach.  The closest I can get to what I imagine you're doing is shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3x8AW). Note that when you do that inner join the input column needs to be fully qualified (`"TestA.id"`, not `"id"`), otherwise you would never be able to chain these things (what happens when you are inner joining an already-joined thing).  If you want me to write this up as an answer I guess I could, but I'm mostly just confused about how you imagine this working.

Comment: If you want to know why, have a look at this https://github.com/AlenToma/expo-sqlite-wrapper Now your solution dose not work for me becouse `TableNames` is very importend for the library I am modifying.

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to spend much time reading through an external repo to understand a SO question, which should be self-contained. Please explain exactly what part doesn't of the suggestion work, preferably with a [mre]; `TableNames` is just a union of two strings and if you don't differentiate them then you're always going to get `"TestA"` and `"TestB"` together all the time, leading to exactly the issue you're having. Feel free to keep using `TableNames`, but you'll need a generic like `D extends TableNames` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjD91m) to keep track of the distinction.

Comment: this seems good except that I do not want to assign `TestB` string here `InnerJoin<TestB, "TestB"`, it should inherit `N` somehow

Comment: "inherit" from where; do you mean *infer*?  TS doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) so you either have to manually specify both or infer both.  Maybe the right thing is to pass the full mapping from table names to table types at the start like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgDqvN)?  Anyway I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: This is not possible for me to use as my `expo-sqlite-wrapper` library is ment to be used not just for me but other developers. So the types is always dynamicly. And this is why `TableNames` is used as the library it self is not aware of the user tables

Comment: I am not suggesting that the library know about `Database`; I'm saying instead of the user passing in `TableNames`, they pass in `Database` which contains the information in `TableNames` plus the types they map to.  But at this point it unfortunately looks like we're not really making progress toward a solution or a clarification of the question, so I think I'll have to disengage now.  Good luck!

Comment: No problem, thx for puting to much time helping, I was thinking of maby there is a way to  `include keyof T and execlude keyof B` and then adding the result to gather. We know of type T and B there must be a way we could `Omit` this. Will have to wait maby someone could solve this if not then I may forget about including the changes. thx again